# how i can to convert code html to text and save it in relational Bd

Tags: angular, postgresql, spring-boot

I want to save a code html in my db , it will be sent from frontend project angular to backend project spring boot and db postgresql.
**how i can to convert my html code to text** ?
[exemple of code what i want to save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTw77.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the template, you can dynamically export the inner HTML as follows:

```html
<div *ngFor="let field of page.fields"> 
    <div #thisElement (focusout)="getHTMLContent(thisElement)">
    </div>
</div>
```

And in the component, you can get it as follows:

```js
getHTMLContent(element) {
    console.log(element.innerHTML);
}
```

You can then include `element.innerHTML` with the request and save it to the database.